# Human is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Human) .solution?

Tags: java

```
public class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Human(String givenName, int age) {
        this.name = givenName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String introduce() {
        return "Hey! I'm " + name + " and I'm " + age + " years old.";
    }

    public int CompareTo(Human h1, Human h2) {
            int hum1 = h1.getAge();
            int hum2 = h2.getAge();
            System.out.println(hum1 - hum2);
    }
}
```

This code for sorting the arraylist using age parameter and this error msg appears

> ./Human.java:6: error: Human is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method compareTo(Human) in Comparable public class Human
>   implements Comparable

What's wrong here? Help please.

Comment: Your CompareTo is wrong [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-)

Answer (score 4):

You want to change:

```
public int CompareTo(Human h1, Human h2)
```

to:

```
public int compareTo(Human h_other)
```

Two things: First, the "c" is lowercase. Secondly, the `compareTo` method compares `this` to another `Human`, so it's equivalent to (using your old code):

```
public int compareTo(Human h_other) {
    return CompareTo(this, other);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the `compareTo` method signature wrong. As a result, the compiler is telling you that you haven't implemented the `Comparable` interface as specified. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) for the correct method signature.

It should be something like:

```
public int compareTo(Human other) {
    return Integer.compare(this.getAge(), other.getAge());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here,you are implementing Comparable interface,

```
public int CompareTo( Human h1);
```

the above method from Comparable interface can have only one argument. You are implementing that with two arguments. that is the problem.